# How to detect whether an app is running on a mobile device or on the desktop

Tags: application-development, qml, ubuntu-sdk

I'm using the Ubuntu SDK to develop a QML app that runs both on the desktop and on mobile devices. Depending on where it's running on the desktop or on a device, certain behaviours should be different.

What's the recommended way of programmatically detecting whether an app is running on the desktop or on a mobile device?

Comment: I think it can be done by checking proess status

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment the only way to detect it is by checking the Application's width and height. For instance assuming that the phone's widthxheight is 40x71 GU (default portrait), the tablet is 160x100 GU (default landscape), anything that goes above 160x100 GU can be considered as desktop.

There are plans to provide flags to identify for instance whether there is a HW keyboard attached, pointing device, ASO, however those flags should not be used alone to identify a desktop form factor as you can attach mouse/HW keyboard to phone/tablet through bluetooth.

Comment: Thanks! I've also now come to realize another important bit of information: you can set a fixed window size for the desktop, on the phone it automatically opens full-screen

Answer (score 0):

@zsombi so something like this?

```
MainView {
    id: mainView
    objectName: "mainView"
    applicationName: "myapp"
    automaticOrientation: true
    width:  units.gu(40)
    height: units.gu(71)

    //detect whether an app is running on a mobile device or on the desktop, base on screen-size
    property bool desktop: false;
    function sizeChanged()
    {
        if(mainView.width > units.gu(160) && mainView.height < units.gu(100))
           desktop = true;
        else
            desktop = false;
    }
    onWidthChanged: {
        sizeChanged();
    }
    onHeightChanged: {
        sizeChanged();
    }
}
```

Then you can make an

```
if(desktop) 
    //Desktop  
else 
    //mobil
```